# jQuery attr command

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a value to the onchange event, but the JS code has errors

```
$(args).attr('onChange', 'setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$cpBody$txtDate\',\'\')', 0)');
```

anyone see error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the proper jQuery/ best Javascript way:

```
$(args).bind('change', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        __doPostBack('ctl00$cpBody$txtDate','');
    }, 0);
});
```

Although why the 0ms timeout period?

You can change your code to:

```
$(args).bind('change', function () {
    __doPostBack('ctl00$cpBody$txtDate','');
});
```

With only the most minor functional difference (`__doPostBack` will be executed immediately instead of ASAP).

It's better to provide a function as the first argument of setTimeout, as opposed to a string. `setTimeout` is closely related to `eval`, and `eval` is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(args).bind('Change','setTimeout('
           __doPostBack(\'ctl00$cpBody$txtDate\',\'\')', 0)');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(args).bind('change', function(e){
    setTimeout(function(){
       __doPostBack('ctl00$cpBody$txtDate','');
    }, 0);
});
```

should fit a little bit better.